# two nouns for "do it now" and "delay it to the future"

Tags: nouns

I am writing a research paper whose title is about "doing things now or delaying them to the future." To be more formal, I hope to use two nouns to represent the same meaning. It is not hard to find a noun for "delaying things," which is "postponement." However, I really had a hard time finding a noun for "doing things now". One word I found is "preproperation," but this word means expediting things or rushing to do things. It is not exactly "doing things now". Can anyone help with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The best I can come up with would be "Immediate Execution" or "Immediate Action." If you're writing a paper, you probably want the title to be clear and concise, instead of using words so grandiose that could hinder the meaning. As they say, "eschew obfuscation." :)

Comment: Difficult, and yet such a reasonable question. I would like to offer you action on it but can only give you procrastination.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give 'base' definitions; all these also have appropriate noun forms, which I give in parentheses.

***prompt***: 'performed readily or immediately' ***(promptenss)***

***expeditious***: 'marked by or acting with prompt efficiency' ***(expeditiousness)***

On the other side, consider

***procrastinate***: 'to put off intentionally and habitually' ***(procrastination)***

***dilatory***: 'characterized by procrastination: tardy' ***(dilatoriness)***

For what it's worth, I think *promptness vs procrastination* has a nice ring to it…